# Function is applied to too few arguments in haskell

Tags: haskell

I just started learning haskell and i'm not able to solve this issue. Can someone tell me why i get error that `g` is applied to too few arguments in the code below.

```
f :: Int -> Int
f first  = 5+first

g :: Int -> Int -> Int
g  first second = first+second


compute :: (Int -> Int) -> (Int -> Int -> Int) -> Int -> Int -> Int
compute f g x y = (f . g) x y
```

Comment: Technically, you cannot apply a function to too few arguments, because every function takes *exactly* one argument.

Comment: This should be the other way around with the brackets: `compute f g x y = f (g x y)`.

Comment: Thank you very much @WillemVanOnsem :)

Comment: @chepner, you can of course fail to apply it to any arguments at all. And if you're applying `seq` to a function (don't do that!) things get more subtle.

Comment: @dfeuer I don't count not applying it as a degenerate form of application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, look at the definition of `f . g`:

```
f . g = \x -> f (g x)
```

Then we can expand the definition of `compute` as follows:

```
compute f g x y = (f . g) x y
                = (\z -> f (g z)) x y
                = (f (g x)) y
                = (5 + (g x)) y
```

`g x : Int -> Int`, for which there is no `Num` instance, so you can't add it to 5.

The problem is that you want `g` applied to both `x` *and* `y` before its result is passed to `f`. To do that, you need something more than simple composition. The simplest way to write this is directly:

```
compute f g x y = f (g x y)
```

If you are aiming for something more point-free, you need to get fancy with the composition:

```
compute f g = \x -> \y -> f (g x y)
            -- application is left-associative
            = \x -> \y -> f ((g x) y)
            -- def'n of (.)
            = \x -> f . (g x)
            -- eta abstraction
            = \x -> (\z -> f . z) (g x)
            -- def'n of an operator section
            = \x -> (f .) (g x)
            -- def'n of (.)
            = (f .) . g
```

---

If you want to be *completely* point-free, you can write

```
compute = (.) . (.)
```

You compose the composition operator with itself.

Comment: Stylistically I prefer to write this sort of composition as `fmap f . g`: `fmap` in the `(->) r` functor is just `(.)`, but written as `fmap` it’s more clearly “mapping over” or “skipping” an argument, so `(f . g) x y` = `f (g x) y`, `(fmap f . g) x y` = `f (g x y)`; or with higher numbers of arguments: `(fmap (fmap f) . g) x y z` = `f (g x y z)`, and so on.

Comment: @JonPurdy Odd. What motivates using `(.)` instead of `fmap` at the last layer? Why not `fmap (fmap f) g` instead of `fmap f . g`, for example, and `fmap (fmap (fmap f)) g` instead of `fmap (fmap f) . g`?

Comment: @DanielWagner: The fact that it’s fully applied, I suppose, and I still want the overall expression to look like a pipeline; to me, the `fmap` is clearer to read than a section with `(.)`, but it’s also just an incidental bit to get around the fact that `(.)` is only really made for single-valued/linear dataflow pipelines. Similarly, I think `f <$> getX <*> getY` is clearer than the specialised `f . getX <*> getY`, because the former has the typical idiomatic `… <$> … <*> … <*> …` pattern of applicative code.

Answer (score 8):

A common mistake is to think that the function composition operator `.` passes along "as many arguments as needed". But this isn't the case: it threads only one argument through.

So when you write

```
(f . g) x y
```

you are probably hoping that this meant

```
f (g x y)
```

but it actually means

```
f (g x) y
```

-- that is, `y` gets passed to `f` as a second argument, instead of `g`. Whoops!